# Permission Issues with ls command

Tags: permissions, cygwin, ls, user-permissions

I am a beginner. I have kept my nauty files in C:\cygwin\home\jim\n , I would like to use

> ls

to see files in n,but I am getting error after

> ls

coomand in cygwin.

> $ ls
>   -bash: /usr/bin/ls: Permission denied

[image]

How can I solve the problem?

PS: Do I need to include any special package?